# Java Spring Thymeleaf dropdown is disabled and appear

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have:

```
<select th:unless="${#strings.contains(session.userProfile.permission, 'UPDATE_GENERAL')}" disabled="disabled" id="kt_select2_10" name="sbSmtpSecurity">
<option th:value="false">None</option>
<option th:value="true" th:selected="${systemSetting.sbSmtpSecurity}">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I want to disable this select if there is no userProfile permission.

Problem is: if I have the disabled attribute, the drop down does not appear. 
If I removed disabled attribute, the dropdown list appears.

Can I have disabled and the drop down appear together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:unless` makes the entire tag disappear.  Instead, use `th:disabled` and set the condition using Thymeleaf.

```
<select th:disabled="${!#strings.contains(session.userProfile.permission, 'UPDATE_GENERAL')}" id="kt_select2_10" name="sbSmtpSecurity">
  <option th:value="false">None</option>
  <option th:value="true" th:selected="${systemSetting.sbSmtpSecurity}">Yes</option>
</select>
```